# Getting incremented day when using components date in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calendar

I am using below code to get the day from components.I have a as `2017-01-08 18:38:00 UTC`.I am using below code to to get teh day from it.

```
 var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day,.weekday
      ], from: eventModel.start_date!)
    print("component day is \(String(describing: components.day!))")
```

But when i print the day it gives me day as 9 but not as 8 so what is the issue with code.Please guide me how can i improve this thing.

Comment: Are you in the correct timezone for your calendar?

Comment: The issue you are facing is because of your Timezone simply set the `UTC` timezone to your calendar will solved your problem.

Comment: What code changes i need to make in order to get this working

Comment: @iOSGuy It is simply like `calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!`

Answer (score 0):

Print(calendar.timeZone). I think it was your local timezone.

---------update-----------

```
var cps = DateComponents()
cps.year = 2017
cps.month = 1
cps.day = 8
cps.hour = 18
cps.minute = 30

print(cps)

var cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let localDate = cal.date(from: cps)!
print(localDate) // 2017-01-08 10:30:00 +0000

let timezone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
cal.timeZone = timezone!
let utcDate = cal.date(from: cps)!
print(utcDate) // 2017-01-08 18:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: What code changes i need to make in order to get this working